# Unexpected Generics Behavior

Tags: c#, generics

I was discussing a related matter with someone on chat and I came up with this code which behaved differently than I had expected.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Test<SomeObject>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class SomeObject
{
    public SomeObject() { }

    public new string ToString()
    {
        return "Hello world.";
    }
}

class Test<T> where T : new()
{
    public Test()
    {
        T t = new T();
        object t1 = t;
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(t1.ToString());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
<ProjectName>.SomeObject
<ProjectName>.SomeObject
```

Because the first line is written from the generic type I expected it to use the ToString() method defined in SomeObject since that's what the type would become at run time wouldn't it?

Comment: No, generics are early-bound.  Overload resolution uses generic constraints, but not the actual type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Ben Voigt has given you the answer in his comment.

You could achieve the result you’re expecting by specifying the type that declares the hiding (`new`) method implementation as a generic constraint:

```
class Test<T> where T : SomeObject, new()
{
    public Test()
    {
        T t = new T();
        object t1 = t;
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(t1.ToString());
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Hello world.
Program.SomeObject
```

**Edit**: The compiler resolves any member invocations on generic types against the generic constraints. This is implied in the MSDN C# Programming Guide on [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> By constraining the type parameter, you increase the number of allowable operations and method calls to those supported by the constraining type and all types in its inheritance hierarchy. Therefore, when you design generic classes or methods, if you will be performing any operation on the generic members beyond simple assignment or calling any methods not supported by System.Object, you will have to apply constraints to the type parameter.

To help clarify matters: Imagine that you had defined a new method, `Foo`, in your class:

```
class SomeObject
{
    public SomeObject() { }

    public void Foo() { }
}
```

Attempting to call `Foo` would result in a compile-time error. The only thing the compiler knows about generic type `T` is that it has a parameterless constructor – it has no knowledge of any methods it might define.

```
class Test<T> where T : new()
{
    public Test()
    {
        T t = new T();
        t.Foo();   // Error: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Foo' 
                   //        and no extension method 'Foo' accepting a
                   //        first argument of type 'T' could be found
    }
}
```

However, if you constrain `T` to be of type `SomeObject`, then the compiler would know to look for the definition of `Foo` within the `SomeObject` class:

```
class Test<T> where T : SomeObject, new()
{
    public Test()
    {
        T t = new T();
        t.Foo();   // SomeObject.Foo gets called
    }
}
```

The reasoning is quite similar for hidden members.

Comment: Oh wow. That seems even stranger to me! Do you know the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @SpencerRuport, when you specify an inheritance constraint on T for SomeObject, you give more information to the compiler. It now knows that T is always SomeObject or a derived class, so it knows to call the new ToString method

Comment: @SpencerRuport: Replied within answer.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: Suppose `foo`:`bar`:`boz`; `boz` defines a virtual method `m` returning `int`, which `bar` overrides; `foo` declares a "new" method with that same name which returns `string`.  All perfectly legal.  Suppose a method is defined as having generic parameter `p1` of type `T` constrained to `boz`.  If that method is called with a variable of type `foo`, what should be the type of `p1.m()`?

Answer (score 1):

In `Test<T>`, the compiler doesn't know that `T` will actually be `SomeObject`, since there's no constraint on `T`. So it can only assumes that `t` is an `object`, and the call to `t.ToString()` results in calling the virtual `Object.ToString` method, *not* `SomeObject.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

This has absolutely nothing to do with generics, and everything to do with the fact that you declared a *new* method called `ToString`, instead of *overriding* the existing one.

If you had overridden the method instead, it would've been used, this has nothing to do with early-bound compared to late-bound either (as indicated by other answers here.)

The reason why calling `ToString` on the `T` reference does not differ from the `object` reference is that the compiler has no way to verify that *all* `T`'s that can be used here has defined *that* new `ToString` method, and it thus has to fall back to the one inherited from object in *all* cases.

Note that the compiler will produce a method that will be used by *all* variations of `T`, regardless, so it has to use the knowledge it has about T, and you have not stated that you inherit from an interface or a class (although in this case I doubt it would make a difference) so the compiler has no way of knowing that `ToString` has been overridden in this case.

If, on the other hand, you *had* stated that the `T` in question is a descendant of `SomeObject`, the compiler would know that it has a *new* `ToString` method to use, but this knowledge is not available to the compiler with just the `T` alone.

Comment: It was his intention to hide the inherited method – otherwise, he would not have expected to see any difference when calling it from an `object` reference.